# How to replace the number in a nested list with symbols?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

It seems that I have to make it in detail; it's my homework.  I don't
want to copy the code written by you.  I'm a newbie; what I'm trying
to learn is how to decompose a subject to single pieces, and then
focus on what function should I use to solve the problem.  It's a
little hard to finish these problems by my own, because I'm completely
a newbie in Lisp, actually in how to program.  I hope you can help me
out.

Here is the problem: there is a given constant

```
(defconstant *storms* '((bob 65)
                        (chary 150)
                        (jenny 145)
                        (ivan 165)
                        (james 120)))
```

Each storm is represented by a list of its name and its wind speed.

The wind speeds are to be categorized as follows:

39–74 → `tropical`
  75–95 → `cat-1`
  96–110 → `cat-2`
  111–130 → `cat-3`
  131–155 → `cat-4`
  156 or more → `cat-5`

Now I have to write two functions:

- `storm-categories` should generate category names, like this: `(bob
  tropical)`, `(chary cat-1)`, …
- and `storm-distribution` should generate the number of storms in
  each category, like this: `(cat-1 1)`, `(cat-2 0)`, …

The way I try to solve this problem is:

1. Use `if` statements to judge the type of windspeed:

   (if (and (> x 39) (< x 73)) (print 'tropical)) 
   (if (and (> x 74)  (< x 95)) (print 'cat-1))
   (if (and (> x 96) (< x 110)) (print 'cat-2))
   (if (and (> x 111) (< x 130)) (print'cat-3))
   (if (and (> x 131) (< x 155)) (print'cat-4)) 
   (if (and (> x 156)) (print 'cat-5))
2. Replace the windspeed (like `65`) with windtype (like `cat-1`)

   (loop for x in *storms*
         do (rplacd x ‘windtype)

I just have a simple idea of the first function, but still don't know
how to implement it.  I haven't touched the distribution function,
because I am still stuck on the first one.

Comment: yes,it's my homework.. I'v already revised the problem.

Comment: the you should use the homework tag: 'Homework means the asker is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they should guide the student in solving the problem, rather than simply showing the complete answer. '

Comment: There are a lot of typos in your text (example 'STROM-DISTRIBUTION' instead of 'STORM-DISTRIBUTION).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay roccia, you have posted your answer. Here comes mine hacked in a few minutes, but it should give you some ideas:

First let's start with the data:

```
(defparameter *storms2004*
  '((BONNIE 65)
    (CHARLEY 150)
    (FRANCES 145)
    (IVAN 165)
    (JEANNE 120)))

(defparameter *storm-categories*
  '((39  73  tropical-storm)
    (74  95  hurricane-cat-1)
    (96  110 hurricane-cat-2)
    (111 130 hurricane-cat-3)
    (131 155 hurricane-cat-4)
    (156 nil hurricane-cat-5)))
```

A function that checks if a value is between two bounds. If the right bound can also be missing (NIL).

```
(defun between (value a b)
  (<= a value (if b b value)))
```

Note that Lisp allows the comparison predicate with more than two arguments.

Let's find the category of a storm. The Lisp functions `FIND` and `FIND-IF` find things in lists.

```
(defun storm-category (storm-speed)
  (third (find-if (lambda (storm)
                    (between storm-speed (first storm) (second storm)))
                  *storm-categories*)))
```

Let's compute the category for each storm. Since we get a list of (storm wind-speed), we just *map* over the function which computes the category over the list. We need to return a list of storms and category.

```
(defun storm-categories (list)
  (mapcar (lambda (storm)
            (list (first storm)
                  (storm-category (second storm))))
          list))
```

Now we take the the same list of storms, but use a hash table to keep track of how many storms there were in each category. `MAPC` is like `MAPCAR`, but only for the side effect of updating the hash table. ÌNCF increments the count. When we have filled the hash table, we need to map over it with `MAPHASH`. For each pair of key and value in the table, we just push the pair onto a result list and then we are returning that result.

```
(defun storm-distribution (storms)
  (let ((table (make-hash-table)))
    (mapc (lambda (storm)
            (incf (gethash (second storm) table 0)))
          (storm-categories storms))
    (let ((result nil))
      (maphash (lambda (key value)
                 (push (list key value) result))
               table)
      result)))
```

Test:

```
CL-USER 33 > (storm-category 100)
HURRICANE-CAT-2

CL-USER 34 > (storm-categories *storms2004*)
((BONNIE TROPICAL-STORM)
 (CHARLEY HURRICANE-CAT-4)
 (FRANCES HURRICANE-CAT-4)
 (IVAN HURRICANE-CAT-5)
 (JEANNE HURRICANE-CAT-3))

CL-USER 35 > (storm-distribution *storms2004*)
((HURRICANE-CAT-5 1)
 (HURRICANE-CAT-4 2)
 (HURRICANE-CAT-3 1)
 (TROPICAL-STORM 1))
```

Looks fine to me.

Comment: That's very clear. but I think I still need more time to read your code. especilly the last part, make-hash-table. it still confused me..

Answer (score 4):

DEFCONSTANT is wrong. It makes no sense to make your input a constant. A variable defined with DEFVAR or DEFPARAMETER is fine.

Instead of IF use COND. COND allows the testing of several conditions.

You don't want to use PRINT. Why print something. You want to compute a value.

RPLACA is also wrong. That's used for destructive modification. You don't want that. You want to create a new value. Something like RPLACA might be used in the function DISTRIBUTION (see below).

Use functional abstraction. Which functions are useful?

- BETWEEN-P, is a value X between a and b ?
- STORM-CATEGORY, for a given wind speed return the category
- STORM-CATEGORIES, for a list of items (storm wind-speed) return a list of items (storm category). Map over the input list to create the result list.
- DISTRIBUTION, for a list of items (tag category) return a list with items (category number-of-tags-in-this-category).
- STORM-DISTRIBUTION, for a list of items (storm category) return a list with items (category number-of-storms-in-this-category). This basically calls DISTRIBUTION with the right parameters.

The function DISTRIBUTION is the most complicated of the above. Typically one would use a hashtable or a assoc list as an intermediate help to keep a count of the occurrences. Map over the input list and update the corresponding count.

Also: a good introduction into basic Lisp is the book [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) - it is freely available as a PDF for download. A more fun and also basic introduction to Lisp is the book [Land of Lisp](http://nostarch.com/lisp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**Finally finished this problem. the second part is really makes me crazy. I cant't figure out how to use hashtable or assoc list to slove it. Anyway the assignment is done, but I want to know how can I simplify it... Hope u guys can help me** . Thanks for your help Joswing, your idea really helps me a lot...

```
(defconstant *storms2004* '((BONNIE 65)(CHARLEY 150)(FRANCES 145)(IVAN 165)(JEANNE 120)))

(defun storm-category (x) ; for given windspeed return the category
(cond
((and (> x 39) (< x 73) 'tropical-storm))
((and (> x 74) (< x 95) 'hurricane-cat-1))
((and (> x 96) (< x 110) 'hurricane-cat-2))
((and (> x 111) (< x 130) 'hurricane-cat-3))
((and (> x 131) (< x 155) 'hurricane-cat-4))
( t 'hurricane-cat-5)

)
);end storm-category

(defun storm-categories (lst) ;for a list of storm and windspeed return storm's name and wind type
(let ((result nil))
(dolist (x lst (reverse result)) ;
(push
(list (first x) (storm-category (second x)) ) result)
)

)

);end storm-categories

    (defun storm-distribution (lst)
    (setq stormcategories '(tropical-storm hurricane-cat-1 hurricane-cat-2 hurricane-cat-3 hurricane-cat-4 hurricane-cat-5))
    (setq stormlist (storm-categories lst))
     (let(    (tropicalcount 0)
              (hurricane-cat-1count 0)
              (hurricane-cat-2count 0)
              (hurricane-cat-3count 0)
              (hurricane-cat-4count 0)
              (hurricane-cat-5count 0)
              (result nil)
         )

    (dolist (y stormlist )

    (cond
         ((eql (second y) 'tropical-storm) (setq tropicalcount (+ tropicalcount 1)))
         ((eql (second y) 'hurricane-cat-1) (setq hurricane-cat-1count (+ hurricane-cat-1count 1)))
         ((eql (second y) 'hurricane-cat-2) (setq hurricane-cat-2count (+ hurricane-cat-2count 1)))
         ((eql (second y) 'hurricane-cat-3) (setq hurricane-cat-3count (+ hurricane-cat-3count 1)))
         ((eql (second y) 'hurricane-cat-4) (setq hurricane-cat-4count (+ hurricane-cat-4count 1)))
         ((eql (second y) 'hurricane-cat-5)(setq hurricane-cat-5count (+ hurricane-cat-5count 1)))
    )
    );ebd dolist


    (push
          (list  (list 'tropicalstorm tropicalcount ) 
                 (list 'hurricane-cat-1 hurricane-cat-1count) 
                 (list 'hurricane-cat-2  hurricane-cat-2count ) 
                 (list 'hurricane-cat-3  hurricane-cat-3count ) 
                 (list 'hurricane-cat-4  hurricane-cat-4count ) 
                 (list 'hurricane-cat-5  hurricane-cat-5count ) 
          ) ;end list
    result) ;end push

    );end let

    );end distribution
```